# JavaScript prevent Overwriting in localStorage

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I am working on a Vue project and I am creating shopping cart. When you press on the button the item details are passed to localStorage and from within it is displayed in the shopping cart.

The problem is when I press on new product to put it in the cart - my key gets overwritten and because of that I can have only one item in the cart.

Related code:

```
tobakset(){
    var size = this.ssize;
    var color = this.scolor;
    let obj = {s : size, c : color, n : this.link(this.links).name, id : this.link(this.links).id}
    this.items.push(obj)
    localStorage.setItem(STORAGE_KEY, JSON.stringify(this.items));
}
```

Comment: This is because you are storing a single item object. Perhaps put these objects in an array and place the array on local storage instead. You’ll need to retrieve the array if it already exists and push to it if it does.

Comment: How does `this.items` get created? As @Lewis mentions, you'll probably want something like `this.items = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(STORAGE_KEY));` somewhere in there...

Answer (score 1):

```
toBasket() {
  const obj = {
    s: this.ssize,
    c: this.scolor,
    n: this.link(this.links).name,
    id: this.link(this.links).id,
  };
  this.items.push(obj);
  const currentItems = localStorage.getItem(STORAGE_KEY) || '[]';

  localStorage.setItem(
    STORAGE_KEY,
    JSON.stringify([...JSON.parse(currentItems), ...this.items])
  );
},
```

This should work. Though it feels a bit wrong. If we're storing basket items in localStorage, you probably want to load those into the cart as soon as the appropriate component is created.

```
created() {
  const currentItems = localStorage.getItem(STORAGE_KEY) || '[]';
  this.items = JSON.parse(currentItems);
},
```

Now you can just do this for your `toBasket()` method, because you just sync'd the cart with the stored items in localStorage:

```
toBasket() {
  const obj = {
    s: this.ssize,
    c: this.scolor,
    n: this.link(this.links).name,
    id: this.link(this.links).id,
  };
  this.items.push(obj);
  localStorage.setItem(STORAGE_KEY, JSON.stringify(this.items));
},
```

### Bonus points:

Use Vuex to store your cart items, and the npm package [vuex-persistesd-state](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vuex-persistedstate) to automatically sync the Vuex cart module with localStorage.